# What is the recommended cluster size for a Spark job with 35,000 partitions

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm using Dataproc 1.4 and I have a Spark Job with 35,000 partitions (input size is 3.4 TB). I'm using 120 nodes clusters of n1-standard-4 machines (so 480 cpus).

The problem is that I ran into network errors during shuffles (same results with external shuffle service enabled or disabled), e.g.

```
"Connection to xxx:44035 has been quiet for 120000 ms while there are outstanding requests. Assuming connection is dead; please adjust spark.network.timeout if this is wrong."
```

Is there any recommendation on the number of partitions per node?
Should I use more nodes or bigger instance types?

**edit 2021-08-23**

As suggested in the comments, I've tested with 128G and 256G of disk and both runs had the same write speed (~ 4 GiB/s)

[image]

- Between 3:00 and 3:20, the spark was reading the input and writing the shuffle files. The CPU consumption is quite low (~40%). Why?
- After 3:20 PM, a new stage was reading shuffle files to write the output and the job failed

Comment: Could you provide more details about your cluster? Are these 120 nodes all primary workers? Is autoscaling enabled? Is EFM enabled?

Comment: all primary nodes. no autoscaling. no EFM.

Comment: How large is the disk size for workers?

Comment: disk size is 100G SSD

Comment: Disk size is too small, the recommended is 1TB at least. If SSD is too expensive for you, just use the default PD. https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/support/spark-job-tuning#optimize_disk_size

Comment: Did increasing disk size solve your problem?

Comment: no, as you can see in my edit

Comment: I see that you tried with 128 and 256GB, but not with 1TB. Can you please try that and let us know if it helped?